# Word Embedding for Sentiment Analysis

Tags: natural-language, word-embeddings, sentiment-analysis

I am working on sentiment analysis of text. I am using keras word embedding.
If my embedding has a vocabulary of 50 and an input length of 4 and I choose an embedding space of 8 dimensions, how will be the output from the embedding layer?

Comment: 50 what? What model are you talking about? What is the framework you are using? Without such minimum information it is impossible to help you.

Comment: i updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in [Keras Documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/), your embedding layer output will be of dimension:

```
(<batch_size>, <input_length>, <embedding dimension>)
```

i.e. in your case it is `(None, 4, 8)`, where `None` stands for your batch size. The vocabulary size doesn't affect the output dimension, but you need to input it while constructing your `Layer` object.